# How can I get grid row/col position given an item index

Tags: javascript, math, grid

If I have a container with a width of 1000px, filled with items all of which are 200px in width.  How can I calculate that tiles row/column position?

To explain in more detail:

[image]

The only variables I will know is the width of the container (1200px in the above example) , the width of an item (200px above) and the items index (starting at 1).

Given only the above information, how can I calculate the row and column of a cell by inputting its index using javascript.

e.g. Given a maximum items per row value of **6** (which can easily be calculated from the item width and container width), I need to be able to calculate that item number **7** is at **row 2, column 1**.

The container and item width's might not always be divisible exactly so the equation will have to account for any extra whitespace requires at the end of each row and naturally wrap the items onto the next row as they would in an html float layout.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

I have managed to get the row quite accurately by doing the following:

```
var itemsperrow = Math.floor(containerwidth/ itemwidth);
var column = Math.ceil(itemindex / itemsperrow )
```

This is with the items index starting at 1 and not 0;

Comment: And what HTML and CSS are you working with?

Comment: Can you please include what you have tried and how/why it didn't work?

Comment: @DavidThomas the HTML/CSS is largely irrelevant to this question and it is purely the math that I am looking for. I just need to understand how to calculate row/column for an item by its index.  If it helps all items are fixed width (200px) and (display: inline-block).  The container width will change but I will always now what the width of that container is in advance to performing the row/column calculation.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I've tried several rough formulas, but none have been correct.  Math is a real weak point for me.  I have managed to get the row using the following formula Math.ceil(index / columnstotal) with columnstotal being calculated like so: Math.floor(containerwidth/ itemwidth).  Though I haven't tested this with huge numbers of items yet.

Comment: What does it mean `items index'` ?
You can not define cells after 6 if you do not know height of boxes.

Comment: items index means the cells index from left to right starting from 1.  I do not need to know the height as I do not need to know the top offset of the item, only its row.  Given a maximum items per row value of 6, I should be able to calculate that item number 7 is at row 2, column 1.  I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Find how many elements fit in one row by taking the floor of (row width)/(element width).
2. Divide the index number given by the elements per row (which you just figured out). That will give you the row position.
3. Next find the column position by taking the remainder portion from step 1 (you can use modulus). Multiply the remainder by the number of elements per row. That will be which column it is in.

example: 3 elements per row, 4th element:
floor(4/3) = 1 (row 1)
remainder = (4%3)=1 (column position)

Be careful of what index you are starting with (whether it's 0 or 1). This example starts at 1. If you want to start at 0 shift it over by subtracting 1 (the index number).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.  I was very close it seems, but this has done the trick :)

Comment: Should be `example: 3 elements per row, 4th element: ceil(4/3) = 1 (row 1) remainder = (4%3)=1 (column position)` Use floor in the first step, ceil in the second.

Comment: For me I would say this example isn't that easy to follow, the question in in JavaScript and so the example should be too, using variables and statements, Not a text description all on one line.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('.container').children(),
    container_width = 1200,
    cell_width = 200,
    total_cols = container_width/cell_width,

    calculateCoords = function (index) {
        return coords {
            col: index%total_cols,
            row: Math.ceil(index/total_cols)
        };
    };

//EXAMPLE USAGE FOR CELL INDEX = 3;
var index_3_coords = calculateCoords(3);
console.log(index_3_coords); //{ col: 3, row: 1 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example.  This does it perfectly.  unfortunately user829323 beat you to the post by a couple of minutes and I have already awarded him the answer.  I hope you don't mind.  Cheers!

Comment: I will note that the ceil used here works and I had to change the floor on the second step on the accepted answer to ceil in order to get that one to work. This is the more correct answer.